# Why can't I start Java using the Process class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I am trying to start a java process with some arguments but when I try to start Java it doesnt work at all because it throws this exception.

```
'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

Why is that? The environment variables should be fine because I can type `java` into the cmd and it prompts me with Java related stuff.

```
Process clientProcess = new Process();
            clientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
            clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-jar " + @"C:\Users\computer\Desktop\Minecraft Spigot\spigot.jar" + " " + "argumentsFortheJarFile";
            clientProcess.Start();
```

Comment: `java.exe` probably isn't in your process' `PATH`.

Comment: Try to just execute the `.jar` file. Maybe, set the `WorkingDirectory`, if required.

Comment: Oh, that's what you add? I thought it was the path to the `bin` folder. I might just add it using C# then.

Comment: @Dai I tried adding it but no go, still the same

Comment: There is a space in the path to the jar file, hence it is handled as two separate command line arguments. Put the path in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try verifying following 4 points:

1) Make sure environment variable `PATH` is set for JAVA.

2) As, jimi suggested in comments, Use the working Directory of 'java.exe' installed in your system

```
clientProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = '<Path_to_directory_for_java.exe>';
```

3) Use 'java.exe' as filename

```
clientProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
```

4) Provide arguments with double quotes, specially if argument values contains space in itself..

```
clientProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @" -jar " + @"\"C:\Users\computer\Desktop\Minecraft Spigot\spigot.jar\"" + " " + "\"argumentsFortheJarFile\"";
```

Comment: A call to the static method: `Process.Start(@"[Some .jar file]");` will test whether the `java.exe` path is actually registered as a System Environment `Path` (not User `PATH`). The installer does that on its own. The error reported could also be generated by arguments not correctly specified. Using the wrong quotes, or inserting quotes where thay're not required, is a classic.